# When a .csv file is opened in excel and saved as an excel sheet .does it have the same properties as that of an original excel sheet?

Tags: c, excel, csv

I am working on a project that records the in time and out time Using C programming for attendance system. It was very difficult to write that data into EXCEL sheet format using C . So what I did was saved the data to a .csv file and saved it as a excel sheet.
Does the newly saved file have the same properties as that of actual excel sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actualy if you open a CSV file with excel, it will Automatikly be Converted in excel Format. When you save this file, it will then keep this format.

Comment: To excel Format. when saving it, in csv format, it does't allways works. But this is not needed, since the file is already in csv format.